# SQL Server User Defined Table Types and BCP Export

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp, table-valued-parameters

I can't seem to get this script to work. I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@TVP_GLICU".

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

```
Declare @TVP_GLICU TVP_GLICU 
DECLARE @cmd varchar(500)
Declare @TimeStamp as nvarchar(100) = Replace((CONVERT(varchar(25), getdate(), 121)),':','')

--Insert Batch numbers in user defined table types 
Insert Into @TVP_GLICU (ID)
Values ('563704')
Insert Into @TVP_GLICU (ID)
Values ('498721')

--select * 
--From @TVP_GLICU 

SET @cmd = 'BCP "EXECUTE [F0902].[D365O].[Get-F0911NewRecords]'+@TVP_GLICU+'" QUERYOUT "D:\D365O\DataSource\F0911\'+@TimeStamp+'.csv" -c -t\^, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ''
EXECUTE MASTER..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a table variable from BCP that was created outside the scope of the `query` parameter. When BCP is executed, it creates a new session and the scope of table variables is limited to the session that created the table variable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are concatenating string and are trying to append a table-valued type:

```
SET @cmd = 'BCP "EXECUTE [F0902].[D365O].[Get-F0911NewRecords]'+@TVP_GLICU+'" QUERYOUT "D:\D365O\DataSource\F0911\'+@TimeStamp+'.csv" -c -t\^, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ''
```

Can you instead create a Staging table in the database and use its name in BCP query?